# Addding arrows in closed curves

Tags: plotting, graphics

A simple sample code

```
c0 = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, ContourShading -> False, 
     ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
```

[image]

My question is how to add the two arrows indicated in the above plot? The position of the two arrows should not be random. One should be at an angle $\pi/4$ and the other at an angle $5\pi/4$. I should also be able to control the size, color and orientation of the arrows.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a post-processing trick often shown off around here to change the `Line` object of the plot into `Arrow` objects:

```
c0 /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.1, 3/8}, {0.1, 7/8}}], Arrow[x]}
```

gives

[image]

**Edit - radius invariant positions**

The reason the position of the arrows changes with radius is because sometimes the graphics created by ContourPlot are defined in a clockwise direction and sometimes an anticlockwise direction. The way to deal with this is to sort the points into a known direction. Thus:

```
rules = {GraphicsComplex[x_, y_] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[SortBy[x, ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] + (\[Pi]/2) &], 
    y /. Line[pts_] :> {Arrowheads[{{-0.1, 1/8}, {-0.1, 5/8}}], Arrow[pts]}]
  }

Show @@ Table[
  ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == r^2, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ContourShading -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}] /. rules, {r, 5, 1, -1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But what if I want to with arrows a clockwise direction?

Comment: If you look at the docs for `ArrowHeads` you can see how to change everything about the position, size orientation etc. To reverse the direction you want to specify a negative size so change the `0.1` to `-0.1`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html

Comment: If I change the radius of the circle then the positions of the arrows also change. Is there a way to obtain automatically the two arrows at $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ for every radius and for every value of plot points?

Comment: Yes. See the edit

Comment: Great! Many thanks!